# Question on existence of coproducts.

Tags: category-theory

I need help with the following question, first of all I am not sure about the definition of $\text{Hom}(x,y)$, is this simply either the empty set of the set consisting of the unique function between two elements? I tried to find a counterexample, for example taking $\mathbb{Z}$ with the usual order, I also tried the set $\{0 \}$, $\{1 \}$, $\{0,1 \}$ and $ \{\varnothing \}$ with the inclusion order. Any hints?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *very* good way to proceed would be to answer the second part of the problem first:

> How can you describe such a product (coproduct) in more familiar terms?

Here, "more familiar terms" means using the language of partial order rather than the language of categories. Take your definition of (co)product and unfold what it means in the particular case of *this* category.

Note that the parts of the definitions that say that such-and-such an arrow must be *unique* turn out to be satisfied *automatically* because there is no hom-set with more than one element *anyway*. For the same reason, the parts of the definition that ask for two arrows (with the same beginning and end) to be *identical* will be satisfied automatically too.

The only parts of the definition that remain are the one that talk about whether arrows between certain objects *exist at all*.